# Converting Parse Image file to base64 for saving in zip file

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to download a group of image files that I am retrieving from Parse and save them to a zip file using JSZip. From [this link](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-do-i-convert-an-image-to-a-base64-string-in-cloud-code) it seems like I should be able to get the base64 encoding just by calling .base64 on my image object. I also tried toString('base64'). My zip file generates with files of the correct names but the contents of the files are empty. Am I missing something here?

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: result.get('image').url() }).then(function(response) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.setData(response.buffer);

    var base64Image = image.data().base64;
    zip.folder('images').file(imageName, base64Image, {base64: true});
    return Parse.Promise.as('Success')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to solve it by treating image.data() as asynchronous:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: result.get('image').url() }).then(function(response) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.setData(response.buffer);

    return image.data().then(function(data) {
        zip.folder('images').file(imageName, data.toString('base64'), {base64: true});

        return Parse.Promise.as('Success');
    });
})
```